# how to find out if a linear function is surjective only from domain

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**How can I find out if this function is surjective , bijective without using dim of image or kernel of f (because its in the second question)?**

f:R4-->R3 
f(x, y, z, t) = (2x + y + t, x + y, x + y − z) 
prove that f is a linear function. is it bijective ?surjective? 
find the dim of kernel(f)
should I just give a guess or something? 
I don't really know how to answer without using rank theorem .

Comment: "give a guess or something?" - what would be the goal of that? You know immediately that $f$ can't be bijective, because the domain and codomain have different dimensions.

Comment: @Bungo what about surjectivity ?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to compute the kernel, the most straightforward approach would be to determine whether you can find $(x,y,z,t)$ such that $f(x,y,z,t) = (1,0,0)$, and similarly for $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Or more generally, can you find three linearly independent vectors in the image of $f$?

Comment: @Bungo thank you for the answer , do you mean we know that f is in span{f(e1),f(e2),f(e3)}} so we see if its  free ?

Comment: e1,e2,e3 make a base for R3

Comment: Example: $f(0, 0, 0, 1) = (1, 0, 0)$, so $(1,0,0)$ is in the image of $f$. Can you show that $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ are also in the image of $f$? (Indeed they are.) That will prove that the image of $f$ is all of $\mathbb R^3$, hence $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @Bungo so if i find x,y,z,t which give me a base in the destination group (R3) means its surjective !? I didn't get this

Comment: Yes, if $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and you show that $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ are in $\text{image}(f)$, then that implies that $\mathbb R^3 = \text{span}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\} \subseteq \text{image}(f)$, hence $\mathbb R^3 = \text{image}(f)$, which means that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I got it Thank You sir